# Is there any way to connect to running powershell script using openssh?

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, ssh, terminal

So I have a Windows machine with running powershell processes in Windows Terminal.

Is there any way to connect to that session/process and view its output using openssh? (trying to connect from mac os)

I tried to search for something similar, but apparently nobody cares about such specific requests :)

Comment: You can use RDP over an SSH tunnel - Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You do ssh to Windows machine (assuming you have there `ssh` server). Then you open PowerShell prompt and execute:

```
PS C:\> Debug-Process -Name "NameOfPowerShellProcess"
```

For more information you can visit this [MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/debug-process?view=powershell-7.3)